# Not able to import google libraries

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I'm not able to import google libraries. The errors are:

> The import com.google.api.client.http cannot be resolved
>
> The import com.google.api.client.googleapis cannot be resolved

and several similar errors.. I'm trying to write a program using gdata apis for google calendar.

I've downloaded all the required google api addons. I've changed the build target to (google api+ android versions of) 1.5,1.6,2.1,2.2 from the project properties, and then cleaned the project each time. It is not working for any of them. I'm still getting the same error.

Additional info : I'm running on Vista 32-bit, Eclipse Helios 3.6.2

Comment: I have the same exact problem as you. I have included the gdata-client jars, etc.. Any update? Did you ever resolve this problem?